# What is the exact meaning of the parameter database.history on Debezium?

Tags: mysql, debezium, mysqlbinlog

We are working on a project using Debezium to Stream data from a Database reading the binlog to a message broker. Working on it a bit deeper, and trying to understand better the tool, two questions related the configuration parameters came up:

- What is exact meaning of the parameter `database.history`?
- And what is the differences between the possible values `MemoryDatabaseHistory` and `FileDatabaseHistory`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

database history serves to record evolution of database schema over the time. It is used by Debezium to create a correct data from historical event in case the schema in database has been changed.
`MemoryDatabaseHistory` should be used only for testing as it does not survive restart. `FileDatabaseHistory` should be used only for Debezium Embedded. If you use Debezium iniside Kafka Connect then you should use `KafkaDatabaseHistory`.